Feature scaling for recurrent auto encoder network
I have 5 dimensional input to my model. The model in question is recurrent autoencoder there were are talking about unsupervised learning.
Those features are physical variables, and for my purposes it seems it is viable to calculate derivatives of those features to help model. However, I have problems with how to scale those derivatives. In some cases, some of the dimensions are almost constant, only variation is noise from measurement. If I scale all derivatives to <0,1>, then I am artificially overstating noise as potentially important change. Originally, I scaled the original variables to <0,1>, since I know their maximal ranges, and then calculated derivatives. However, in some cases derivatives are bigger than 1, and I am facing problem of potentially exploding gradients.
What is a reasonable approach to scaling of derivatives so the original nature of data is preserved.
